# Recycler View supporting multiple pojo classes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pojo

I have a requirement where i have a single recycler view which should be supported by multiple model classes.
My recycler view will inflate multiple different layouts . So to inflate layout i have defined my onCreateViewholder like below :

```
     @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        switch (viewType) {
            case 1:
                View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchresultsrow1, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new AppViewHolder(v1);
                break;
            case 2:
                View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchresultsrow2, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new AppViewHolder(v2);
                break;
         return viewHolder
}
```

On bindview method i use instance of to determine holder type : `

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if(holder instanceof AppViewHolder){
            AppViewHolder vh1 = (AppViewHolder) holder;
vh1.appName.setText(Html.fromHtml(**appList**.get(position).getmAppName());
}
} else if (holder instanceof ContactViewHolder){
ContactViewHolder vh3 = (ContactViewHolder) holder; vh3.contactName.setText(Html.fromHtml(**contactList**.get(position).getContactName()));}
}`
```

Now i am clueless what to send on itemCount :

```
  @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return  ??;
    }
```

Since my **applist** object type is different and **contact** list object type is different. **I have tried with switch case in getItemCount but then it only returns the count of single list and displays results only for the particular list whereas i want results combined of both the list**. 
If i send the addition of both the list , then i will encounter **arrayindexoutofbounds** exception. 
What approach can be used in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want results combined of both the list:

Since you want both lists result in recyclerView, Create a List of type object and add all contents of both list to this list. Then in `onBindViewHolder()` check for `list.get(position) instanceOf YourClass` then carry on your operation based on type.

In `getItemCount()` return the size of combined list.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(appList != null && contactList != null)
        return appList.size() + contactList.size();
    else
    {
        if(appList != null)
            return appList.size();
        else if (contactList != null)
            return contactList.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

**Caution:** You will have to keep track of number of items rendered from each list and use that index to get the item from corresponding list, otherwise you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExcetption`. Don't use current position to get the item from list.

**Update**

Keep two variables

```
private int appListIndex = 0;
Private int contactListIndex = 0;
```

at class level.

Then do this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if(holder instanceof AppViewHolder){
        AppViewHolder vh1 = (AppViewHolder) holder;
        vh1.appName.setText(Html.fromHtml(appList.get(appListIndex++).getmAppName());
    }
    } else if (holder instanceof ContactViewHolder){
        ContactViewHolder vh3 = (ContactViewHolder) holder;     
        vh3.contactName.setText(Html.fromHtml(contactList.get(contactListIndex++).getContactName()));
    }
}
```

Comment: i have done that already, but my requirement is it should display the combined results. If i use if else, at a time it will display only results of the single array list

Comment: @Gautam Updated my answer.

Comment: In this case, lets assume both the list contains 5 elements then it will return 10 & it will cause arrayindexoutofbounds in onBindView. Since the position can vary and it can be greater than 5 which i won't be finding inside any of my arraylist.

Comment: you will have to maintain individual counter for each list starting from 0 to size -1. Use that index to get the item rather than position.